# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined even it exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

UPDATE TO SIMPLIFY THE QUESTION:

Problem accessing property by string index but works using keys

```
for(var i in this.props.data[this.props.activeMenu]){
    console.log(i, this.props.data[this.props.activeMenu][i]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
url /api/timekeeping
name Timekeeping
submenus Object {dtr: Object, schedules: Object}
id timekeeping
```

But I have error when calling `console.log(i, this.props.data[this.props.activeMenu]['name'])`. `name` is a valid key since it was displayed when I checked the keys.

Comment: Please share more code.

Comment: when I tried to check **console.log(this.props.data['timekeeping'])**. The output is **Object {url: "/api/timekeeping", name: "Timekeeping", submenus: Object, id: "timekeeping"}**

Comment: Yes, we have already talked about it. Can you share a file from where you think the error has occurred?

Comment: The code you are showing is fine ... so the problem must be somewhere else. We need to see more

Comment: @lolka_bolka there is no semantic difference to OP's code

Comment: @devnull69 You are right, I misread something..

Comment: What is the EXACT value of `this.props.activeMenu` with regards to case sensitivity?

Comment: As @devnull69 said, it would work if you had that object with that key at the time of doing the console log

Comment: thank you guys. I have update and added more info.

Comment: @DominicTobias Yes you are right, I can access it with no problem using keys, but I can't access using string 'name'? Is there any way I can access it directly?

Comment: @rechie I don't see your problem ... with your latest edit you say that it works as needed? Where is your console.log code located relative to your latest code edit? Inside or outside the success callback??

Comment: @devnull69 thats why it really gives me headache. when i tried `for(var i in this.props.data[this.props.activeMenu])` and call `console.log(i, this.props.data[this.props.activeMenu][i])` where `i = 'name'`, it works fine.

Comment: you still did not answer my questions ... hence my downvote

Comment: You have to be careful: Sometimes what you see is not exactly equal to what you have with regards to e.g. special characters etc. If you are absolutely sure that the key is EQUAL to 'name' and not ' name' or '%uAF54name' than it must work

Comment: Not to forget: You showed code that uses the `['name']` syntax which worked and which was used INSIDE the success callback of an ajax call. With regards to asynchronous calls there could of course also be a race condition in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I found the cause. Yes, during React Initialization data is null and that causes the error. After fetching the data from server, it worked. That's why, traversing the keys using for loop worked because it checks if the data is null or not.

Answer (score -1):

> Blockquote ut when I tried to access console.log(this.props.data['timekeeping']['name']), I got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I think you should use: console.log(this.props.data['timekeeping'].name).

Try it.